# Google App Maker: Prevent Duplicate Entries

Tags: google-app-maker

How do I prevent the user from adding a duplicate entry in a specific field. I have a database in which I want a field to contain unique identifying names for equipment, how do I ensure a user can't add equipment to the database with the same identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add onSave and onCreate Event handlers (Model -> Events) which will check if identifier is in use:

```js
var query = app.models.Hardware.newQuery();
query.filters.HardwareId._equals = record.HardwareId;
if (query.run().length) {
  throw 'Hardware ID "' + record.HardwareId + '" is in use.';
}
```

Also in CloudSQL you can define unique index on the field.

Comment: This worked great. I noticed the error shows in the debug console, is there a way of sending the same message to the user?

Comment: The best way I can think of is to add validation method on server (checkId(string):boolean ) and then call it onValueEdit of the ID like:


google.script.run.withSuccessCallback(function(exists) {widget.validationErrors = exists ? ['ID exists'] : []}).checkId(widget.value);